# Looking for feedback on regex config

Tags: regex

Was looking for a review of a regex I created, as I'm looking to see where improvements could be made

I have the following log message:

```
2017-02-09T14:12:07.381648+00:00 ATA-CENTER ATA[4844] CEF:0|Microsoft|ATA|1.7.5757.57477|AbnormalBehaviorSuspiciousActivity|Suspicion of identity theft based on abnormal behavior|5|start=2017-02-09T14:07:22.1490000Z app=Kerberos shost=xxx suser=Last Name, First Name msg=text here. cs1Label=url cs1=https://xxx-xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx/suspiciousActivity/589c7796135ca912ec5b75b0
```

Here is my regex:

```
.*?\|ATA\|(?<version>.*?)\|(?:\w+)\|(?<alert>.*?)\|(?<severity>.*?)\|(?:.*?)\s\w+=(?<app>.*?)\s\w+=(?<src_host>.*?)\s\w+=(?<user>.*?)\s\w+=(?<msg>.*?).\s.*?
```

I'm trying to disregard everything up to ATA, and then disregard everything after the period at the end of the msg (starting at cs1Label).

Would appreciate any feedback.

Thx

Comment: I would suggest break the such large string into smaller parts and then apply regex. This will make it more manageable and clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one small error in your regex. The dot `.` after the message will match everything. If you really want to match a dot, you need to escape it. `(?:\w+)` will match every character and every digit. You could also just use `\d` to match a digit. Moreover, I wouldn't label the capture groups. In my opinion, this does not make the regex more readable.

Otherwise it seems fine to me. Here is a [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/zX1qCc/1) with the fixed dot.

Comment: thx for the reply and demo link as it was very helpful. I label the capture groups as for Splunk I need to create a field extraction with a key header. I lucked out with these types of events as they have the same message format. Still struggling with the best way to handle log sources that have multiple formats and how to create regexes that apply to what is listed. How would you create a regex for events in which a variable may or may not be listed, or a regex that shows all possible variables? Thx

Comment: You could make a variable optional like this: `(?:(?<severity>.*?)\|)?`. `(?:)` is a non-matching group and the `?` afterwards makes this group optional. The problem here is however, if the format does not differ between the variables, it is very difficult to make one optional and still get the correct order..